# Android - Support Multilanguage app in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, locale, multilingual, screen-rotation

I have a ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter and five tabs that is called from my MainActivity. I want to change dynamically the language of my App. To do this, i saved my language preference in my `onSavedInstanceState` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String predefined_lang = prefs.getString(LANGUAGES, "error");
    String sub_lan = predefined_lang.substring(0,2).toLowerCase();
    outState.putString(LANG, sub_lan);
    System.out.println(">>saveinstance"+predefined_lang);
}
```

and than i retrieve the language from `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    //System.out.println(savedInstanceState.getString(LANG));

    //configuration.locale = new Locale(savedInstanceState.getString(LANG));
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String predefined_lang = prefs.getString(LANGUAGES, "error");
    String sub_lan = predefined_lang.substring(0,2).toLowerCase();
    configuration.locale = new Locale(savedInstanceState.getString(LANG));
    getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
    System.out.println(">>onrestore"+savedInstanceState.getString(LANG));

}
```

So i try to avoid that the chosen language is not changed again in the default language of the device. 
Actually, all string resources are displayed in the correct language, except for the names of the tab of the viewPager. For example:

i have these five tabs:

| tab1 -|- tab2 -|- tab3 -|- tab4 -|- tab5 |

if default language of the phone is in `Italian` but i chose to display the app in `English`, everything is written in English, even the name of the tabs. But when i rotate the screen, everything remains written in English except the names of the tab that, instead, are in Italian. Solutions?

Comment: is the problem only when you rotate the phone?

Comment: yes, only when the screen is rotated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can stop reloading application when orientation changes, by adding to your manifest :

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

and to your MainActivity:

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

    }
}
```

or you can specify any other action, read more about Runtime Changes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

hope this helps

Comment: in my manifest it's already present this line of code: `android:configChanges="orientation|locale"` ...

Comment: it's OK leave it that way, did you put  the other code in your MainActivity about Orientation?

Comment: ok thank you very much! i have removed `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods and instead of these i added `onConfigurationChanged ` method where  i check if the `newConfig.locale` is equal to my desired locale and now it work like a charm!